# How to make use of jndi in a stand-alone (non-managed) application?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

How to make use of jndi in a stand-alone (non-managed) application?
App and Tomcat6 are on the same machine.

Can we get something through jndi lookup when the server is running,
but when the app is not running under this tomcat server?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is your stand-alone app not deployed on Tomcat but running as a Java program?

Comment: @josek yes it is running as a standalone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the Tomcat JNDI outside of the Tomcat web app. I think Tomcat does not expose the JNDI externally. See this link:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q22

Answer (score 0):

Performing a lookup is only a matter of creating an `InitialContext` with the valid parameters. Considering you have a Tomcat running on your machine, you should be able to find the required context parameters in `server.xml`.